# can not receive whatsup message with chat API using php

Tags: php, jquery, api, chat, chatbot

I am using chat API with the PHP for send and receive Whatsapp messages,I can send messages but I am unable to receive message.

This is My reference : https://chat-api.com/en/?lang=EN

Here my PHP code:

```
$url = 'mychatAPI/message?token=tokenId';
$result = file_get_contents($url); // Send a request
$data = json_decode($result, 1); // Parse JSON
foreach($data['messages'] as $message){ // Echo every message
    echo "Sender:".$message['author']."<br>";
    echo "Message: ".$message['body']."<br>";
}
```

I tried with Jquery also :

```
var url = 'mychatAPI/message?token=tokenId';
$.get(url, function (data) { // Make a GET request
    for (var i = 0; i < data.messages.length; i++) { // For each message
        var message = data.messages[i];
        console.log(message.author + ': ' + message.body); //Send it to console
    } 
});
```

I am getting this `Message was not sent: empty body. Please provide message text in body parameter in JSON POST.`  when I echo `$data`

Tell me how can I receive my Whatsapp message by using it chatId or author or is there any way to receive messages.
Or
tell me which API could I use for receiving my whatsup messages or read message by using `PHP or javascript or jquery` .

Answer (score 0):

The error you show us is logic if you tried to get the message, you actually send a POST request to get the message.

Do that :

```
// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'GET'
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```